# Почему не присваиваются значения переменным?

Tags: java

Вектор заполнен и нужно найти его максимальное и минимальное значение.

Почему значения элементов вектора не присваиваются: `minFound` и `maxFound`?

Код:

```
private void foundMin()
{
    minFound = foundValue.get(0);
    maxFound = foundValue.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < foundValue.size(); i++)
    {
        if(foundValue.elementAt(i) > maxFound)
            maxFound = foundValue.elementAt(i);
        if(foundValue.elementAt(i) < minFound)
            minFound = foundValue.elementAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: "значения ... не присваиваются" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: пользуясь дебагером

Comment: Вы партизан? Или разведчик? В каком месте Вы наблюдаете неприсвоенные переменные? После выполнения каких строк кода? Мне начинать гадать?

Comment: Какого типа елементы?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю нужно использовать nameOfVector.get(index);  // вместо elementAt(i);

- вектор переписали на аррэйлист и теперь вектор не актуален

Answer (score 0):

Все работает:

```
Vector<Integer> foundValue = new Random().ints(5, 0, 100).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new));
foundValue.forEach(System.out::println);

int minFound = foundValue.get(0);
int maxFound = foundValue.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < foundValue.size(); i++) {
    if (foundValue.elementAt(i) > maxFound) {
        maxFound = foundValue.elementAt(i);
    }
    if (foundValue.elementAt(i) < minFound) {
        minFound = foundValue.elementAt(i);
    }
}
System.out.println("min = " + minFound);
System.out.println("max = " + maxFound);
```

Результат:

> 60
>   51
>   98
>   20
>   9
>   min = 9
>   max = 98

**PS:** `Vector` в отличии от большинства других реализаций `List`-а потокобезопасен, если вам это не нужно, то лучше использовать, например, `ArrayList`.